# Html <video> tag controls not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have created a video player with playlist. The problem is that the forward control is not working properly as I cannot forward the video. What can be the problem cause it is working fine when working with static video files.

here is my html code. I have used 3 tabs which loads iframe video, normal video and iframe powerpoint. is this creating the problem by overlapping.

```
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">

  <div class="row" id="video_player">

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 playlist">

      {% for slides in tutorial.lecture_set.all %}

      {% if slides.lecture_content %}

      <a href="{{slides.lecture_content.url}}">

       <div class="row mt-2">


         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <img src="{{slides.course.poster.url}}" class="img-fluid" alt="lecture slides">
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-9">
           <p>{{slides.lecture_title}}</p>
         </div>
       </div>

      </a>

    <hr>

     {% else  %}

        <p> There are no slides uploaded.</p>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12">

  <video class="frame" controls="controls" poster="{{ tutorial.poster.url }}" id="videoarea">
     <source src="" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="" type="video/webm">

 </div>
```

Js code:

```
  var video_player = document.getElementById("video_player"),
  links = video_player.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
   links[i].onclick = handler;
   }

  function handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    videotarget = this.getAttribute("href");
    filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget;
    video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
    video.removeAttribute("poster");
    source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");
    source[0].src = filename + ".mp4";
    source[1].src = filename + ".webm";
    video.load();
    video.play(); 

  }
```

Comment: If you open devtools have an error?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini no error sir. it words fine here

  <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
                 <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src="myed_video/video1.mp4"></video>
              </div>

but when i started implementing in django i can play/pause but cannot forward the video

Comment: Does it work when you replace `{{slides.lecture_content.url}}` with a hardcoded URL?

Comment: @hedgie yess sir.. i think the problem is with chrome cause its working fine in other browser..any solution for that

Comment: So there is no difference between the Django-generated source and the handwritten source, yet it doesn't work with the former? That seems impossible!

Comment: @hedgie well what i think is that the browser itself is creating the problem